# Moisture Resistant Drywall Residential code

Tags: drywall

Is there an IRC/IBC code that requires the use of moisture resistant drywall in certain areas of a home?

Comment: there answer to the question is `probably` ..... i am sure that some part of the world has a building code that covers that requirement

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, local code questions are off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because local code questions are off-topic here.

Comment: So, it isn't covered in IBC or IRC? That was basically my question.

Comment: Can you change your question to that?

Comment: What are you asking?